# How to add one accordion control within another accordion control programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, accordion

I have two accordion pane like

```
Accordion a = new Accordion();
Accordion b = new Accordion();
```

in my asp.net web application.
I like to add Accordion b within Accordion a programmatically in c# code behind.
Is it possible to add two Accordion Controls like that?
If any one able to help for that means it will really helpful for my project. 
Many Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help if you can provide us what you want it to look like with non-code behind code so we can help with the code-behind version eg:

```
<asp:Accordion ID="AccordionA" runat="server">
    <Panes>
        <asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPaneA1" runat="server">
            <Header> First Header</Header>
            <Content>Contents with in the first header </Content>
        </asp:AccordionPane>
        <asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPaneA2" runat="server">
            <Header>Second Header</Header>
            <Content>Content with in the second Header</Content>
        </asp:AccordionPane>
        <asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPaneA3" runat="server">
            <Header>Third Header With Accordion</Header>
            <Content>
                <asp:Accordion ID="AccordionB" runat="server">
                    <Panes>
                        <asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPaneB1" runat="server">
                            <Header> First Header</Header>
                            <Content>Contents with in the first header </Content>
                        </asp:AccordionPane>
                    </Panes>
                 </asp:AccordionPane>
            </Content>
        </asp:AccordionPane>
    </Panes>
</asp:Accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try somethin like (not tested - just out of my head):

```
AccordionPane pane = new AccordionPane();
a.Panes.Add(pane);

pane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(b)
```

Comment: Nice guess! But it not working, Can you please give any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Sourced for [this](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit/accordion/dynamically-adding-an-accordion-pane-cs) site, you can try something along these lines:

```
<script runat="server">
void Page_Load() 
{
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
 {
 AccordionPane ap1 = new AccordionPane();
 ap1.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Using Markup"));
 ap1.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(new 
 LiteralControl("Adding panes using markup is really simple."));
 AccordionPane ap2 = new AccordionPane();
 ap2.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Using Code"));
 ap2.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(new 
 LiteralControl("Adding panes using code is really flexible."));
 acc1.Panes.Add(ap1);
 acc1.Panes.Add(ap2);
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I need to nest two accordion not two accordion pane. Can you please give suggestion regarding to that?